# How to add Sub Categories in the WordPress Widgets Categories

Tags: wordpress, widget

How can I add a subcategories inside the Widget--> Categories ,  not in the Post categories. If any body knows please help.

find the image below[image]

Comment: from what I see on the screenshot you provided it looks like there is no active category page on the web...if thats right then do add category and check it again.

Comment: Sorry the normal categories is  working fine, but the the categories in the widget is not working.

Comment: Not the categories in the post., categories in the widgets, CATEGORIES in the WIDGETS

Comment: You can use simpleLink plugins. it is easyest way to add menu in the sidebar with each category